# Проверка пунктуации

Tags: пунктуация

Познав внутреннюю сущность объекта, -- труднейшую философскую категорию, -- вместе с тем познав и всю сущность субъекта, мы переходим к следующей части рассуждения.

Соблюдена ли в данном предложении верная пунктуация?

Comment: Первая запятая у вас чем мотивирована?

Answer (score 3):

Симметрия знаков - красиво, но громоздко. Верю, что как авторская пунктуация допустимо. Однако постановка запятой и тире как единого знака не приветствуется современными пунктуационными нормами.  (Э... можно сказать - не приветствуется нормами? В общем, не приветствуется. Но сочинитель имеет право.)

[Подобный вопрос был задан](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=219299), и Справка Грамоты.ру посвятила изучению его изрядное времечко.

Формально в приведённом предложении могут стоять следующие знаки:

*Познав внутреннюю сущность объекта -- труднейшую философскую категорию, -- вместе с тем познав и всю сущность субъекта, мы переходим к следующей части рассуждения.*

То есть приложение мы обособляем двумя тире, а запятая перед вторым тире обусловлена структурой предложения.

См. примеры и объяснения [**в пункте 9**](http://rus.1september.ru/article.php?ID=200100309):

> Обитатели пригородного морского курорта – большей частью греки и
>   евреи, жизнелюбивые и мнительные, как все южане, – поспешно
>   перебирались в город. (А.Куприн. Гранатовый браслет)
>
> Здесь «встретились» обособленное приложение, выделенное с помощью
>   знака «парное тире», и сравнительный оборот. Нормативное совмещение
>   знаков.

Однако строгое правило гласит:

Второе тире опускается, если по условиям контекс­та после обособленного приложения должна стоять запятая:

***Познав внутреннюю сущность объекта -- труднейшую философскую категорию, вместе с тем познав и всю сущность субъекта, мы переходим к следующей части рассуждения.***

P. S. Добавлю правило оформления распространённых приложений (Розенталь, [§ 93, п. 8, в](http://rosental-book.ru/punct_xxiv.html)):

> Вместо запятой при обособлении приложений употребляется тире
>
> для выделения с двух сторон приложений, носящих пояснительный
>   характер, например: Какая-то ненатуральная зелень – творение скучных
>   беспрерывных дождей – покрывала жидкою сетью поля и нивы… (Гоголь);
>   Легкие судороги – признак сильного чувства – пробежали по его широким
>   губам… (Тургенев) (ср. § 89, п. 4); Смотритель ночлежки – отставной
>   солдат скобелевских времён – шёл следом за хозяином (Федин).
>
> Второе тире опускается:
>
> если по условиям контекста после обособленного приложения ставится
>   запятая, например: *Используя специальное устройство для дыхания
>   человека под водой – акваланг, можно погружаться на глубину в десятки
>   метров;*
>
> если приложение предшествует определяемому слову, например: *Самый
>   лживый, лицемерный и самый влиятельный из всех «учителей жизни» –
>   церковь, проповедуя «любовь к ближнему как самому себе», в прошлом
>   жгла десятки тысяч людей на кострах, благословляла «религиозные»
>   войны* (Горький).

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! А если бы перед "вместе" стоял союз "и", все равно бы пунктуация была такая же?
PS
думаю, можно сказать "не соответствует". :)

Comment: Тогда вопрос был бы только в том, как оформить приложение. Варианты: в двух запятых, в двух тире; два зап-тире как сугубо  авторский знак.

Comment: То есть Вы имеете в виду, что в данном случае можно так и так, или с этим предстоит разобраться? И еще, как русский язык объясняет эти авторские знаки, не идут ли они врозь с литературными нормами?

Comment: Авторские знаки потому так и называются, что "идут ли они врозь с литературными нормами". И - да, можно так (в двух запятых) и так (в двух тире), с этим уже до нас разобрались. ))) Это если подставить союз *и*. Если не подставлять союз, второе тире опускаем.

Comment: Но "адепты" литературного русского языка наверняка не признают это, скажем так, авторское самоволие, раз оно все-таки врозь, так?

Comment: Адепты как раз всё знают об "авторских правах", но если текст предъявлен на оценку по русскому, то самый гладкий вариант тот, что в моём ответе выделен полужирным.

Answer (score 1):

**Предложение неясно по форме,** дело не только в обособленном приложении. Попробуем приложение убрать:  Познав внутреннюю сущность объекта,  (а) вместе с тем познав и всю сущность субъекта, мы переходим к следующей части рассуждения. **Может быть, нужен союз А?**

Приложение в данном случае можно оформить как  **вставную конструкцию**, а вставки всегда обособляются **двумя тире** (делается выбор одной или двух запятых):

**Познав внутреннюю сущность объекта – труднейшую философскую категорию, –  а вместе с тем познав и всю сущность субъекта, мы переходим к следующей части рассуждении.**

Первая запятая не нужна, он **переносится на конец вставки**.

Пример: Заключив тайный договор – его всё-таки пришлось закрепить на бумаге, – великое посольство собралось к отъезду.

Comment: Спасибо! А в каких случаях вставная конструкция обособляется запятой и тире с обоих сторон?

Comment: В этом случае надо обосновать обе запятые. Запятая ПЕРЕД ПЕРВЫМ ТИРЕ ставится в следующих случаях: А) перед вставкой находится обособленный член предложения, не входящий в её состав: День, который она провела в Москве, – потом она часто вспоминала об этом – был тёплым, солнечным. Б) В  начале вставки находится обособленный член , который входит в её состав: Издалека, – должно быть, из  мастерских – тоже откликнулись низкие гудки.  ПРИМЕР ДВУХ ЗАПЯТЫХ: Мечику невольно захотелось всё рассказать самому, – в сущности, он любил такие вещи, –  но ему казалось, что все смотрят на него с удивлением .

Comment: Иногда запятые ставят ДЛЯ СИММЕТРИИ:   Когда Косте пошёл девятый годок, –  я же в ту пору уже невестой была, – повезла я его по всем гимназиям (первая запятая не нужна, но ставится для симметрии).